# What is the meaning of "take-haver"?

Tags: meaning

There's an interesting [article](https://www.motherjones.com/media/2021/11/omicron-variant-pronunciation-classics-scholars-british-american/) in *Mother Jones* on how to pronounce "omicron". (Apparently, both short and long Oh versions are correct.) This sentence appeared near the end

> And while we await the official NPR and Associated Press takes, the typical arbiters of newsreader styles, there’ll be take-havers. There always are.

What is a *take-haver*? I'd never heard of it before.

BTW, I tried to google "define: take haver" or "meaning: take haver" with no luck at all.

Comment: So what's the etiquette on answering your own question within the question? It was/is a genuine question. Do i *need* to split off my answer as a separate post?

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Comment: I suspect that you had no success googling "take-haver" because it isn't an established word or phrase and that the writer made it up on the fly. I'd be pleased to be proved wrong  but only if supported by evidence.

Comment: [From PC Magazine, 1989:](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22people+who+have+a+take+on%22) *Liddle is one of those eminently quotable **people who have a take** on just about everything.* 30 years later, calling Liddle a *"**take-haver**"* doesn't sound ridiculous.

Comment: The important thing to remember about _omicron_ is that it's a Greek word that means "little O" (_micron,_ natch; there's also a _mega_). The stress is on the first syllable, and it should be the same vowel you use to say _omega_. For most English speakers, that's /o/. Probly most American speakers will say /kran/ at the end, but that's not stressed so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Xanne -- I know i'm allowed to answer my own question, but i suspect it is not recommended within the question itself. (The fact that the answer came to me while composing the question is rather novel, though.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- I'd agree, if the immediate context is that someone has an opinion, and the word "take" was used instead of opinion, then "take haver" is somewhat reasonable. Out of context, though, and i'd bet you'd not get many take havers on its meaning :-)

Comment: @JohnLawler -- Thank you, but please don't.

Comment: This is *not* a term in common usage. It's just an ad hoc noun that means people who have takes (opinions) on the situation — *take-havers* = *opinion-havers*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat - OK, but isn't that just what an answers below says?

Answer (score 5):

It means *One who has an opinion (a "take") on something*.

It is probably not an established word or phrase, so the search for a meaning/definition bore no fruit.

However, here are some more examples --all rather obscure-- of actual use:

From [movetoamend](https://www.movetoamend.org/sothranauk) (I *think* they're saying "here's a good opinion...")

> **the best take haver**:
> I’m no one. I don’t want to be anyone. I just want to see the ruling class overthrown and punished.

From [metaphoricalmoose](https://metaphoricalmoose.tumblr.com/) (I'm uncertain what was meant.)

> **the good take-haver**:
> what if we kissed at the neighborhood high voltage box

From [shitliberalssay](https://www.reddit.com/r/ToR_Archive/comments/pog7ji/shitliberalssay_image_the_good_take_haver_has/) (This one is sarcastic.)

> The Good Take Haver has logged on

From [twtext](https://twtext.com/d08890) (If there good ones, then, surely, bad ones too.)

> **N. Bourbaki, Bad Take Haver**:
> WARNING: extremely nerdy thread incoming.

I conclude that it is still a very obscure word/phrase but, perhaps with help from Mother Jones herself, it will become an established one, albeit confusing (or annoying) to some ears.

Comment: I agree that this is the intended meaning, but I think the term "take-haver" is somewhat tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: As for the "the good take-haver has logged on," if you keep clicking the links it's a screenshot of someone saying "social democracy is to the left of Marxism."  "The good take-haver has logged on" is meant to be sarcastic mockery of what the poster believes to be a stupid take.  You might take it as a online-jargon way to say "here comes someone with a brilliant opinion," or something like that that.

Comment: @Casey -- I agree with you, but i'm not sure we need to examine the motives for people's usage.

Comment: Well, no rule that you have to; I just felt I could offer some elucidation where you said there's no context so we have to guess what they meant.

Comment: The answer is in the Question Quote itself ".... we await the official NPR and Associated Press **takes**, .... , there’ll be **take-havers** ...." & so, you could update your answer to confirm, rather than assume, that this is the exact intended meaning.

Comment: @Casey - I see.

Answer (score 0):

OED

> **haver** (n.)  **1. A person who has something (in various senses); (in early use) esp. an owner, a possessor.**
>
> 1944   C. M. Case Ess. Soc. Values 50   *This time binder, memory holder, experience haver, status seeker, ideal cherisher remains always the same.*
>
> 2005   J. Vandever Brontë Project (2006) 149   *She was a haver of affairs, not a carrier of torches.*

A **take-haver** is thus someone who takes (or purports to take) ownership of something, i.e. in this case, the "correct" pronunciation of "omicron".

Comment: I think the term of art here is "take" more than "haver."